# Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver()); method is not work in Android 5.0 and new version,so how to clear the history of chrome in Android 5.0

Tags: android

In my Android application i want to clear the history of Google Chrome on any button click.

`Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());` is working properly in Android 4.2 but not work in Android 5.0 and later version, so how can I clear the history of Google Chrome?.

Answer (score 2):

Android has removed Permission to read and write bookmark after API>=23.
Please refer to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

You have to use workaround in implementing your own browser app and then save bookmarks locally in your own sqllite database.